# How do I make this only work on a command

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a quiz bot on discord using discord.js but when I run this code it replys back even if it's not the right word. How do I fix it?

```
client.once('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'quiz') 
    msg.channel.send('Ok quiz time!');
    msg.channel.send('Can coding be hard. yes  or no ')
    msg.react('').then(() => msg.react(''));
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  return ['', ''].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === msg.author.id;
};

msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ['time'] })
  .then(collected => {
    const reaction = collected.first();

    if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
      msg.reply('correct answer');
      msg.channel.send ('Good job!')
    } else {
      msg.reply('Incorrect.');
    }
  })
  .catch(_collected => {
    msg.reply('You ran out of time.');
  })
  });
```

When I say a random word in discord, my bot will reply to it with "Can coding be hard. yes  or no "

Comment: bruh ur if statement will end on the line right below it.. **USE BRACKETS PLS** because all other lines below `msg.channel.send('Ok quiz time!');` are **OUTSIDE** the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brackets are mis-aligned
Your corrected code should be like this.

```
client.once("message", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === "quiz") {
    msg.channel.send("Ok quiz time!");
    msg.channel.send("Can coding be hard. yes  or no ");
    msg.react("").then(() => msg.react(""));
    const filter = (reaction, user) => {
      return (
        ["", ""].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === msg.author.id
      );
    };

    msg
      .awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1, time: 60000, errors: ["time"] })
      .then((collected) => {
        const reaction = collected.first();

        if (reaction.emoji.name === "") {
          msg.reply("correct answer");
          msg.channel.send("Good job!");
        } else {
          msg.reply("Incorrect.");
        }
      })
      .catch((_collected) => {
        msg.reply("You ran out of time.");
      });
  }
});
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Comment: Please run this through a code formatter.

Comment: fixed, im new to indentation on here sorry.

Comment: Cool! Please be more clear with titles and your issues in future. May get your post deleted if its not clear enough :)